# What does "wget -O" mean?

Tags: wget

I have an wget command like this in my shell script:

```
reponse="`wget -O- http:localhost:8080/app/index.html`"
```

I don't understand the -O- option. I was explained that -O is output to somewhere and - is output to the current stream. I don't see any explaination of "-" in wget. Is that a standard thing for shell scripting. Where I can find reference to it?

Thanks,

Comment: Might want to reconsider accepting @Mingyu's answer?

Answer (score 106):

Here's the man page of wget -O:

**http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Download-Options.html#Download-Options**

Here's a few examples:

1. **wget with no flag**

   ```
   wget www.stackoverflow.com
   ```

   Output:

   A file named as index.html
2. **wget with -O flag**

   ```
   wget -O filename.html www.stackoverflow.com
   ```

   Output:

   A file named as filename.html
3. **wget with -O- flag**

   ```
   wget -O- www.stackoverflow.com
   ```

   Output:

   Output to stdout

Comment: Crisp and precise description. Good one to understand with example.

Answer (score 12):

for the manual of wget: use man wget if you are on Unix platform. Else, try "man page wget" on google.

The -O- stand for "Get as a file and print the result on STDOUT"

Comment: I can't find "Get as a file and print the result on STDOUT" in "man wget". I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: -O allow you to save result in file. The "-" is pipe redirection to STDOUT on linux. Therefore: "Get as a file and print the result on STDOUT"

Answer (score 3):

Here is the syntax:

```
wget -O (filename|-) [url]
```

If you write a "filename" the output will be saved into a file named "filename".

If you put "-" instead of "filename". the output of the code will be represented in stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system you should be able to find reference by typing `man wget`. The GNU Wget man page says this of the `-O|--output-document` flag:

> If `-` is used as **file**, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.  (Use `./-` to print to a file literally named `-`.)

And continues…

> Use of `-O` is not intended to mean simply "use the name **file** instead of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: `wget -O file http://foo` is intended to work like `wget -O - http://foo > file`; **file** will be truncated immediately, and **all** downloaded content will be written there.

It's not uncommon to see combined with `-q` and written as `-q0-` or `-q0 -` followed by a uri. It validates against the POSIX standard so, yeah, I'd say it's a standard thing for shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -O teleComData.csv https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/ML0101ENv3/labs/teleCust1000t.csv
```

This command downloads the csv file from the specified url and saves it as `teleComData.csv`. If you hadn't used the `-O` flag, it would simply save the file as it is.