# What do HTTP code names \\o/ \\o- -o- /o\\ represent in requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Working with status codes in the `requests` library, I encountered something odd. There is a constant for every HTTP status code, some having aliases (including a checkmark for 200, for example):

```
url = 'https://httpbin.org/status/'
r = requests.get(url + '200')
print(r.status_code == requests.codes.ok)
print(r.status_code == requests.codes.all_ok)
print(r.status_code == requests.codes['✓'])
# all print True
```

That makes sense because we don't want to hardcode HTTP status codes and use textual names instead. What I do not understand is the following:

```
print(requests.get(url + '200').status_code == requests.codes['\\o/'])
print(requests.get(url + '404').status_code == requests.codes['-o-'])
print(requests.get(url + '500').status_code == requests.codes['/o\\'])
# all print True
```

Where do the symbols come from? The 404 one looks like the [`-O-` option for wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830242/what-is-o-option-means-for-wget), but that's probably not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like gesturing people (and requests is maybe being a little silly including them, but it doesn't hurt anyone – a little levity is fine now and then).

## 200 – success: `\o/`

Yay!

[image]

## 404 – not found `-o-`

A shrug, maybe?

[image]

## 500 – server error `/o\`

Looks like someone cowering.

[image]

Comment: There's also `\o-` for 301/moved permanently and `✗` for 500/server error. See [`status_codes.py`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/status_codes.py)

Comment: *God dammit I'm a freaking idiot.* Thank you, that must be it, and redirect sort of looks like a person pointing to the right I guess.